# Defining simple string in PHP wont work..

Tags: php

I am a PHP programmer since 12 years now, but i run out of my possibilities now. 
I never had such issue, and i dont know, what's going wrong there.

It is really simply. I want to declare the number 84367 as a variable.

I minimized my script to 1 line, in a new php file, but.. what is going wrong?!

```
<?php
$x = "84367"‬; 
?>
```

results in

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '‬' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\me7dtc\test.php on line 2

Why ?

Comment: Try adding one empty line after <?php and also make sure you save file without BOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. Your code contains a unicode character.

Copy and paste this exactly as shown:

```
<?php
// $x = "84367"‬; 
               ^ unicode hidden character between the last quote and the semi-colon‬.

$x = "84367";
?>
```

The commented line is the one that contains the unicode character.

- To be more specific, it's the (hidden) `&#8236;` character between the last quote and the semi-colon.

A.k.a.: "POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING".

Consult the following links on this:

- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202c/index.htm
- http://www.codetable.net/decimal/8236

This would likely not have shown it when encoded/editing under an UTF-8 environment, but will in ANSI.

In an ANSI encoded environment, it would have shown `â€¬` immediately following the last quote.

More precisely:

```
<?php
$x = "84367"â€¬; 
?>
```

You more than likely were under an UTF-8 coding environment where it is needed for you, but were unable to see it. You could temporarily convert your file to ANSI then switch back to UTF-8 in order to pick up on (hidden) characters such as these.

Comment: But why those characters are in unicode-format ? I type here with Dreamweaver CC, and all settings are like before, and i typed somewhat about 1.000.000 lines code on this notebook before.. 
I dont understand anything now :-D

Comment: @ChristophEder It could be an encoding setting (keyboard) in your program. I haven't used DreamWeaver since its initial release many moons ago. I've been using Notepad++ myself and even regular Notepad for quick edits.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. However, it is working now, since i restarted my Notebook. Dreamweaver restart doesnt helped. It's a really strange thing, only when i tried to type in this 84367 var the error appears, all other var's, code etc worked fine.. I think it is time to go to bed, 5am here, maybe this was the problem.

Comment: @ChristophEder I'm glad to have been of help and please get some sleep, it's one of a coder's best friends ;-) *Cheers* and you're quite welcome.

Comment: @ChristophEder I thought it was the last quote that was the unicode; alas after a digging a bit deeper, found that there is a hidden character between the last quote and the semi-colon. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your time. Sadly, nobody could say me where this character comes from, and getting me a headache for about 1 hour..

Comment: @ChristophEder You're most welcome. Well, it could have been caused by many things. That link I included above, mentions something about PDF, maybe something was copied from a PDF document, or you may have inadvertently pressed a key or a combination of keys, Lordie... it could be anything. Sometimes, mysteries like this hardly ever get explained or knowing what the source was.